# Moss Camo - MGS3

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater

I was battling against The End in Metal Gear Solid 3 for almost 40 minutes. When I pointed the gun in his head, he gave me the moss camo, but before picking it up, I shot him with the MK22, making him die by stamina. I picked up his rifle, but when I returned to the place where he dropped the camo, it wasn't there anymore.
Any chance to still get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, at least not without reloading an earlier save.

The only way to acquire the moss camo is by threatening The End. If you have defeated him and didn't pick up the camo, you can no longer get it.